# Ruby Queue to Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, queue

Is there a way other than this to get all the elements of the queue object?

```
def method queue
    array = []
    until queue.empty? do
        array << queue.pop
    end
    array
end
```

I was trying something like this:

```
def method queue
    Array(until queue.empty? do queue.pop end)
end
```

But that returns an empty array.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times), [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
def to_a queue
  queue.size.times.map { queue.pop }
end
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Array.new(queue.size) { queue.pop }
```

Comment: [Rubocop](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_performance/#performancetimesmap) agrees.

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like:

```
def method(queue)
  [].tap { |array| array << queue.pop until queue.empty? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers empty the queue, which doesn't work for me.

I'm going with:

```
class Queue
  def to_a
    @que.dup
  end
end
```